# Swift Remove Object from Realm

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

I have Realm Object that save list from the JSON Response. But now i need to remove the object if the object is not on the list again from JSON. How i do that?
This is my init for realm

```
func listItems (dic : Array<[String:AnyObject]>) -> Array<Items> {
        let items : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
        let realm = try! Realm()
        for itemDic in dic {
            let item = Items.init(item: itemDic)
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(item, update: true)
                }
            items.addObject(item)
        }
        return NSArray(items) as! Array<Items>
}
```

Comment: Btw i have primary key for the item.id

Comment: You might want to check [realm link](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#deleting-objects) about how to delete...

Answer (score 36):

imagine your `Items` object has an id property, and you want to remove the old values not included in the new set, either you could delete everything with just

```
let result = realm.objects(Items.self)
realm.delete(result)
```

and then add all items again to the realm,
or you could also query every item not included in the new set

```
let items = [Items]() // fill in your items values
// then just grab the ids of the items with
let ids = items.map { $0.id }

// query all objects where the id in not included
let objectsToDelete = realm.objects(Items.self).filter("NOT id IN %@", ids)

// and then just remove the set with
realm.delete(objectsToDelete)
```

Comment: According to the [realm docs](https://www.realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering) this should be `NOT id IN %@`.

Comment: Also, do delete operations inside realm.write{}. Like this: try! realm.write { realm.delete(objectsToDelete)}

Comment: Don't forget to add this delete operation in a write transaction block.

Answer (score 11):

I will get crash error if I delete like top vote answer.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'
```

Delete in a write transaction:

```
let items = realm.objects(Items.self)
try! realm!.write {
    realm!.delete(items)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
func realmDeleteAllClassObjects() {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()

        let objects = realm.objects(SomeClass.self)

        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(objects)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // handle error
        print("error - \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

// if you want to delete one object

```
func realmDelete(code: String) {

    do {
        let realm = try Realm()

        let object = realm.objects(SomeClass.self).filter("code = %@", code).first

        try! realm.write {
            if let obj = object {
                realm.delete(obj)
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // handle error
        print("error - \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is assign a primary key to the object you are inserting, and when receiving a new parsed JSON you verify if that key already exists or not before adding it.

```
class Items: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

When inserting new objects first query the Realm database to verify if it exists.

```
let repeatedItem = realm.objects(Items.self).filter("id = 'newId'")

if !repeatedItem {
   // Insert it
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first suggestion that comes to mind is to delete all objects before inserting new objects from JSON.

Lear more about deleting objects in Realm at https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#deleting-objects

Answer (score 3):

```
do {
        let realm = try Realm()

        if let obj = realm.objects(Items.self).filter("id = %@", newId).first {

            //Delete must be perform in a write transaction

            try! realm.write {
                 realm.delete(obj)
             }
        }

    } catch let error {
        print("error - \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier option to remove 1 object:

```
$item.delete()
```

remember to have the Observable object like:

```
@ObservedRealmObject var item: Items
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var realm = try! Realm()

open func DeleteUserInformation(){
        
   realm.beginWrite()
    
   let mUserList = try! realm.objects(User.self)
   realm.delete(mUserList)
    
    
   try! realm.commitWrite()

    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! FYI your answer has been flagged as low quality by the system because it contains no text, please add a short description for what your code does.